# Setting a layer's Raster Image Marker X/Y location based on the X/Y coordinates of the feature's label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, geometry-generator, qgis-expression

Using QGIS, I'm trying to make a map with Label Callouts that show both the name of the feature, as well as display an image of the feature. I'd like the position of the image to be based on the position of the Label but it seems like `auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx` and `auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony` use the layer's CRS and I can only control the "Offset" of the Raster Image Marker.

How can I make the Raster Image Marker's XY coordinates to be the same or derived from the Label's XY coordinates?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a **Geometry Generator** of geometry type **Point** with the expression:

```
make_point(
  "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positionx",
  "auxiliary_storage_labeling_positiony"
)
```

Then set the **Geometry Generator**'s Marker to **Raster Image Marker**. You can then use the **Offset** settings of the Raster Image Marker to adjust the image relative to the Label.

[image: Geometry Generator Settings]

[image: Raster Image Marker Settings]

Comment: This did the trick - thank you! I'm going to add a screenshot of the setup to your answer.